# Can MS Access 2013 files be converted into the format used by MS Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access-2013

If not, what can I do to convert any info into 2016 format?

I am currently creating a database in v.2013 and am concerned that any additional computers I add within the next year to a network (LAN) that shares this Access database will not be able to access (pardon the pun) this particular file that I am working on.  I am at the beginner level of using Access, and I am sure there are many other people out there like myself who are just getting their feet wet.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Access 2016 can use databases created with Access 2013 just fine, no conversion is needed.